# Convert a variable of non-specific type to string, if possible

Tags: arrays, swift, object

I'm writing a program using many classes, and most of these classes are of special variables that'll convert to a string in a special way, all defined under `.toString()` in their class. I have an `[Any]` called `term` containing many nonspecific items. I want to convert all of them to string and add them to a string called `formatted`.

This is something like what I want to achieve:

```
for item in term as! [Any] {
            formatted += item.toString()
        }
```

Of course, this does not work as `Any` does not have `toString()`. Is there a way to append `toString()` if my object's class has a method `toString()`, and if not, just do something like append an empty string for that object or return an error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is a protocol. You could declare a protocol (let's call it Stringable) that requires a `toString` method, and make all these classes / types adopt the protocol. Now you are guaranteed that if a class / type conforms to this protocol, it has a `toString` method. If you have an array of Stringable, you can send `toString` to any element of that array.

However, that is not what is usually done. `toString` is not Swifty. Swift converts to string by saying `String(whatever)` or `String(describing:whatever)`. All built-in types let you do that. You can add your own types by extending the String type with initializers for your type. Or declare conformance to CustomStringConvertible and implement `description`.

Basically, you are reinventing the wheel. Swift wants you to be able to represent *any* type as a string. Methods like `toString` sound like they are typical of some other language (Ruby?) and are not the Swift way. The `String(describing:)` method already exists and is ready to represent your instance as strings. And arrays of Any are unnatural in Swift and should just about never be used.

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a look into implementing this later. Also, if you don't mind, please can you elaborate on why arrays of Any are unnatural?

Comment: Because Swift is about strict typing. "Any" throws that away.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to skip the `toString()` function and let the classes/structs that has implemented it conform to `CustomStringConvertible` instead and add the required computed property  `description` instead but with the same code as `toString`

So

```
func toString() -> String {
    //some code
}
```

will be

```
var description: String {
    get {
        //some code
    }
}
```

Depending on how your `term` array is defined and used you could either re-define it as

```
var term: [CustomStringConvertible]
```

if all elements will conform to the protocol and then do

```
for item in term {
    formatted += item.description
}
```

If you don't want to change the definition you could try to cast each element

```
for item in term2 {
    if let item = item as? CustomStringConvertible {
        formatted += item.description
    } else {
        formatted += String(describing: item)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, and how do I call this in the main part of my code? Am I right in thinking I use String(describing: item)?

Comment: I am pretty sure that `String(describing:)` calls `description` anyway.

Comment: @Sulthan Yes it does and I am unsure which way is better, I did choose this solution  to prioritise `description` if it is implemented but honestly I don't know if it makes a difference.

Comment: @Sulthan I did a quick test and when printing an array [Any] then `String(describing:)` priorities `TextOutputStreamable` before `CustomStringConvertible` if a type conforms to both. Maybe a slim chance for a custom type but still.

Comment: Joakim and @Sulthan, which protocol is used is defined very well, see my answer and see the apple's docs (jump to definition from xcode context menu)

Answer (score 0):

there are many options, the standard is conforming to proper swift protocols

```
struct S {
    let a: Int
}

let s = S(a: 1)
print(s, String(describing: s), String(reflecting: s))

extension S: TextOutputStreamable {
    func write<Target>(to target: inout Target) where Target : TextOutputStream {
        target.write("TextOutputStreamable")
    }
}

extension S: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        "CustomStringConvertible"
    }
}

extension S: CustomDebugStringConvertible {
    var debugDescription: String {
        "CustomDebugStringConvertible"
    }
}
```

the printing result shows how different protocols are prioritize

```
TextOutputStreamable CustomStringConvertible CustomDebugStringConvertible
```

remove the extensions and it prints

```
S(a: 1) S(a: 1) __lldb_expr_1.S(a: 1)
```

remove extensions one by one and see ... :-)

what about Any?

```
let a: Any = s
print(a, String(describing: a), String(reflecting: a))
```

prints

```
TextOutputStreamable TextOutputStreamable CustomDebugStringConvertible
```

let's try [Any]

```
print([a], String(describing: [a]), String(reflecting: [a]))
```

and the result is

```
[CustomDebugStringConvertible] [CustomDebugStringConvertible] [CustomDebugStringConvertible]
```